# How to check if word is the last word in a string?

Tags: string, actionscript-3

I would like to check if a specific word is the last one in a string. (the string is the user input from a textfield) 
What is a good way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [`lastIndexOf()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#lastIndexOf%28%29):

```
function endsWith(str:String, ending:String):Boolean {
    var index:int = str.lastIndexOf(ending)
    return index > -1 && index == str.length - ending.length;
}

trace(endsWith("Hello World", "World"))
```

Comment: `endsWith('foo', 'fizz'); //true`

Comment: @Aaron Many thanks, works great! Quick question: I'm trying to get the last hashtag in a string: Why does it output **#foo bar** instead of only **#foo**? `var str = "hello world find #foo bar"
var lastHashtag = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf("#"));
trace(lastHashtag);`

Comment: Because if you don't specify an `endIndex` for `substr()` (second argument) it will return everything to the end of the string. Sounds like you want to break on words (spaces)?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, spaces or any other punctation character. (.,;:!? etc)

Answer (score 2):

`/yourword$/.test(string)` is the regex pattern to test if a string ends with a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

Please read documentation. [http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001551.html]

searchString.lastIndexOf("TheWord");